# asp.net mvc 3 return json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

Trying to generate an array on the client side for js:

```
var ds = [{ text: "john", value: "1" }, { text: "paul", value: "2" }];
```

In my asp.net mvc 3 controller I have created a entityframework model and trying to return a list :

```
NORTHWNDEntities db = new NORTHWNDEntities();
public ActionResult GetCustomers()
{ 
    return Json( db.Customers,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

at the moment I cant figure out just to return the customername+customerid property as a list of customers (NWind database)?

Answer (score 10):

Try this - for each customer create a new anonymous object with the properties you want.

```
public ActionResult GetCustomers()
{ 
    var customers = from o in db.Customers
                select new { customerName = o.CustomerName, customerId = o.CustomerId};

    return Json(customers.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Note if you want for ex. "text" and "value" to be the values in your JSON array simply change customerName and customerId above to whatever names you want.

Comment: How could I include a `where` clause in that query?

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
public ActionResult GetCustomers()
{ 
     var customers = for c in db.Customers
            select new { text = c.CustomerName, value = c.CustomerId};

     return Json( customers.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```